# printing the data of list in the order using stream in java

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

I have below List.

```
List<String> firstName = List.of("Monika","Shweta", "Shruti","Anuradha");
List<String> lastName = List.of("Mishra","Hariharno","Sharma","Mishra");
List<Integer> sal = List.of(5000000,50,500,100000);

List<List<?>> finalList = List.of(firstName,lastName,sal);
finalList.stream().flatMap(s->s.stream()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

When I am printing using `flatMap()` it is printing all `firstname`, `lastname`, and then `sal`.

I want to print `firstName : lastName:sal` together for all of them in order.
for eg

```
Monika:Mishra:5000000
```

is it possible using `flatMap` or any other `java8` feature?

Comment: How did you end up with a design including those lists to begin with? It’s bad, and I very much understand your desire to convert them to something better.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is *possible* but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
List<List<?>> result = IntStream.range(0, sal.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> List.of(firstName.get(i), lastName.get(i), sal.get(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Instead, create some type to represent your objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this in one list, you can set up a class containing all your data. Then create a list of your custom objects and print each field in the `forEach`